# Подскажите как с помощью owl-carousel вывести в консоль сообщения

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Подскажите как с помощью owl-carousel вывести в консоль сообщения при возникновении следующих событий: инициализация слайдера, переключение слайда, изменение размера слайдера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подробнее о `callback`'ах и `event`'ах Owl Carousel'и читайте [тут](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html).

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
// обязательно прописать до самой инициализации слайдера
owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function() {
  console.log('установлен');
});
owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 2,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: true
}).on('resize.owl.carousel', function() {
  console.log('resized');
}).on('translated.owl.carousel', function() {
  console.log('слайд прееключен');
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```